# Why is the email alert sent from the salesforce email address instead of the email specified in the 'from email address'

Tags: email, process-builder, email-alert

I created a process that gets triggered only when a case is created. The process sends an email to the user who submitted the case(issue) via email. The email does get sent but the issue here is that the email address that it gets sent through is not the address specified in the 'from address' but from a salesforce address which is not what I want. I wanted the email to be sent through the email address specified in the field 'from email address'. Any help regarding this issue?

Also I also used auto-response rule and the same thing happened. The email got sent from xxxx.sandbox.salesforce.com and not from the email that I specified.

Answer (score 1):

For this requirement, you could set up [Organization wide Email Addresses](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=orgwide_email.htm&type=5)

If your Salesforce org requires users to share a common email alias, you can define a list of organization-wide addresses for each user profile. When sending email from Salesforce, users with these profiles can select their own email address or the organization-wide email address for the email’s From field. Replies are delivered to the selected address.

> Your org has several users assigned to a Support Profile. This profile is associated with an email address called support@acme.com and a Display Name of Acme Support. When these users send an outbound email through Salesforce, they can choose to have their From email address appear as support@acme.com instead of their own Salesforce email address.

Comment: My mistake, I didn't notice that actually, the email that I'd specified in the field 'from email address' was also there in the mail that was received by the issue sender. In the response mail, this is the format in the 'from' field: <techsupport@xyz.com>via xxxxx.sandbox.salesforce.com. But what confuses me more now is why don't I see the response mail in the 'sent' mail section of techsupport@xyz.com? Any ideas why?

Comment: Also, I couldn't find any Support Profile listed in the profile page. Do I need to create one?